# Storing two seperate data fields into an array c# Array Json from Class

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, json, class

Hi I have the following Code whereby in my class I have defined all the classes that I will need to build up my `JSON` string for an eventual put request. I am trying to put my `AttributeColor` and `AttributeSize` Fields into that attributes `string[]` so that the `JSON` returns the following :

```
{"group":null,"productid":"42","sku":"211","money":"20.00","categoryid":"42","attributes":["42","green"]}
```

```
myObject.attributes = reader["Sizeattribute"].ToString() + reader["ColorAttribute"].ToString();
```

where am I going wrong? how can I add two fields to this one array for perfect JSON? Right now I am getting the error Cannot implicitly convert type `'string'` to `'string[]'`

Code Snippet:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace JSON_Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Read From SQL 
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server = localhost;Database=xxxx;UID=admin;PASSWORD=xxxx"))
            {
                String query = "SELECT * FROM [test].[dbo].[DimProductVariantXXX] "; // Please Change the View that you are pointing towards

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    List<Product> myObjectList = new List<Product>();
                    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    if (reader.HasRows)

                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            Product myObject = new Product();
                            myObject.productid = reader["productid"].ToString();
                            myObject.sku = reader["sku"].ToString();
                            myObject.money = reader["money"].ToString();
                            //  myObject.categoryid = Convert.ToString(reader["categoryid"]);
                            myObject.attributes = reader["Sizeattribute"].ToString() + reader["ColorAttribute"].ToString();
                            //    myObject.variantparentid = reader["variantparentid"].ToString();
                            myObjectList.Add(myObject);
                        }
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(myObjectList);
                    Product product = new Product();
                    String JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
                    string path = @"D:\json\product.json";
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        File.Delete(path);
                        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                        {
                            tw.WriteLine(JSONresult.ToString());
                            tw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else if (!File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        using (var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
                        {
                            tw.WriteLine(JSONresult.ToString());
                            tw.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Product
    {
        public Group group;
        public string productid { get; set; }
        public string sku { get; set; }
        public string money { get; set; }
        public string categoryid { get; set; }
        public string sizeattribute { get; set; }
        public string colorattribute { get; set; }
        public List<string>[] attributes { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Product` class, the `attributes` property should be defined as a single list or array.  It's currently defined as an array of `List<string>` (not sure if this is a typo).

Update the definition:

```
public List<string> attributes { get; set; }
```

Now, `myObject.attributes` is a `List<string>` so you need to initialise the list and add the values to it.

You could do this using the [Collection Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers):

```
myObject.attributes = new List<string> 
                      { 
                          reader["Sizeattribute"].ToString(), 
                          reader["ColorAttribute"].ToString() 
                      };
```

This should produce the expected JSON.